# np.fft.ifft2 turns image completely black

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have been working on this for about five hours. I have read the opencv docs and tried copying their sample code and am still unable to get the results I want.

I just want to do the inverse Fourier transform on my image, but after I run the np.fft.ifft2 function all the pixel values drop to almost 0.

I'm sorry for the long post but I would really appreciate the help.

```
# Reading and Resizing image
img = cv.imread('image.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
width = int(img.shape[1] * 0.25)
height = int(img.shape[0] * 0.15)
dim = (width, height)
img = cv.resize(img, dim, interpolation=cv.INTER_CUBIC)

f = np.fft.fft2(img)
fshift = np.fft.fftshift(f)
magnitude_spectrum = 20*np.log(np.abs(fshift))

plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Input Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(magnitude_spectrum, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Magnitude Spectrum'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()

# Making masks
rows, cols = img.shape
crow, ccol = rows//2, cols//2

low_pass_mask = np.zeros((rows, cols), np.uint8)
low_pass_mask[crow-100:crow+100, ccol-100:ccol+100] = 1

high_pass_mask = np.ones((rows, cols), np.uint8)
high_pass_mask[crow-100:crow+100, ccol-100:ccol+100] = 0

# Applying filters
low_pass_filtered = magnitude_spectrum * low_pass_mask
low_pass_filtered_shifted = np.fft.ifftshift(low_pass_filtered)

high_pass_filtered = magnitude_spectrum * high_pass_mask
high_pass_filtered_shifted = np.fft.ifftshift(high_pass_filtered)

# Displaying results of filters in frequency domain
plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(low_pass_filtered_shifted, cmap='gray')
plt.title('low_pass_filtered_shifted'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(high_pass_filtered_shifted, cmap='gray')
plt.title('high_pass_filtered_shifted'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()

# Transforming images back to the space domain
low_pass_result = np.fft.ifft2(low_pass_filtered_shifted)
low_pass_result = np.abs(low_pass_result)

high_pass_result = np.fft.ifft2(high_pass_filtered_shifted)
high_pass_result = np.abs(high_pass_result)

# Displaying Results
plt.subplot(121), plt.imshow(low_pass_result, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Low Pass Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122), plt.imshow(high_pass_result, cmap='gray')
plt.title('High Pass Result'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

[Image before and after transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my2z1.png)

[Image after shifting, applying masks, and shifting back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2VW6.png)

[Image after applying inverse transform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTJVc.png)

Comment: You need to filter the magnitude (not the spectrum), then combine with the phase and then IFFT. But better to work with real and imaginary images. See my post below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# read input and convert to grayscale
#img = cv2.imread('lena_gray.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img = cv2.imread('lena.png')

# do dft saving as complex output
dft = np.fft.fft2(img, axes=(0,1))

# apply shift of origin to center of image
dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)

# generate spectrum from magnitude image (for viewing only)
mag = np.abs(dft_shift)
spec = np.log(mag) / 20

# create circle mask
radius = 32
mask = np.zeros_like(img)
cy = mask.shape[0] // 2
cx = mask.shape[1] // 2
cv2.circle(mask, (cx,cy), radius, (255,255,255), -1)[0]

# blur the mask
mask2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (19,19), 0)

# apply mask to dft_shift
dft_shift_masked = np.multiply(dft_shift,mask) / 255
dft_shift_masked2 = np.multiply(dft_shift,mask2) / 255


# shift origin from center to upper left corner
back_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(dft_shift)
back_ishift_masked = np.fft.ifftshift(dft_shift_masked)
back_ishift_masked2 = np.fft.ifftshift(dft_shift_masked2)


# do idft saving as complex output
img_back = np.fft.ifft2(back_ishift, axes=(0,1))
img_filtered = np.fft.ifft2(back_ishift_masked, axes=(0,1))
img_filtered2 = np.fft.ifft2(back_ishift_masked2, axes=(0,1))

# combine complex real and imaginary components to form (the magnitude for) the original image again
img_back = np.abs(img_back).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
img_filtered = np.abs(img_filtered).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)
img_filtered2 = np.abs(img_filtered2).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)


cv2.imshow("ORIGINAL", img)
cv2.imshow("SPECTRUM", spec)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("MASK2", mask2)
cv2.imshow("ORIGINAL DFT/IFT ROUND TRIP", img_back)
cv2.imshow("FILTERED DFT/IFT ROUND TRIP", img_filtered)
cv2.imshow("FILTERED2 DFT/IFT ROUND TRIP", img_filtered2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("lena_dft_numpy_mask.png", mask)
cv2.imwrite("lena_dft_numpy_mask_blurred.png", mask2)
cv2.imwrite("lena_dft_numpy_roundtrip.png", img_back)
cv2.imwrite("lena_dft_numpy_lowpass_filtered1.png", img_filtered)
cv2.imwrite("lena_dft_numpy_lowpass_filtered2.png", img_filtered2)
```

Low Pass Mask:

[image]

Low Pass Mask blurred (antialiased):

[image]

IFT from Mask:

[image]

IFT from filtered Mask:

[image]